Equivalent characterizations of Jacobson rings
We say that a commutative ring (with unit) $R$ is Jacobson if every prime ideal is the intersection of all the maximal ideals containing it.
I'm struggling to prove that a commutative ring $R$ being Jacobson is equivalent to the following:

If a prime ideal $P \subset R$ is such that $(R/P)[1/r]$ is a field for some $r \in R/P$, then $P$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.

While trying to prove the equivalence I have established that if $R$ is Jacobson then so is $R/I$ for any ideal $I \subset R$ and $R[1/r]$ for any $r\in R$, but I'm unable to come up with any way to show the equivalence.

Some things that might help you:  this is usually phrased as "$R$ is Jacobson iff every Goldman ideal is maximal."  Also, "hilbert ring" is sometimes a synonym for "jacobson ring."  Reference (but not proof for) this theorem appears in wikipedia in the Jacobson ring article. I was able to find this mathoverflow post on the topic, too.  At worst you can dig up kaplansky's proof.  Maybe with these terms you will have a better time finding hints in the literature.

A proof of this fact can be found in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a View towards Algebraic Geometry in Lemma 4.20.
